# Titanium build issue: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

```
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
  File "/Users/ravindrakumar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.2.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1460, in main
    execute_xcode("iphoneos%s" % iphone_version,args,False)
  File "/Users/ravindrakumar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.2.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1215, in execute_xcode
    output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
  File "/Users/ravindrakumar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.2.GA/iphone/run.py", line 41, in run
    sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

I tried cleaning entire project and also i deleted entire iphone folder in build, still i am getting same error.

Also I uninstalled the titanium sdk completely and reinstalled it again, still I am having same build error.

Comment: start xCode for a try. Does it need updates of that sort? Happened to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I was using jQuery in the Webview which was loading a local HTML file.

Titanium SDK was trying to compile the entire jQuery to its appropriate Objective-C, then I added the following code to execute jQuery in the webview.

```
var scriptFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, 'script.txt');
var webkitScript = scriptFile.read().text;
webview.evalJS(webkitScript);
```